# Snap-On impact driver Flyback Diode identification

Tags: diodes, identification, flyback

I have a Snap-On impact driver with a blown diode. I believe it's a flyback diode as it's on the output of the switch up to the motor.

I can make out several markings on the diode. C39 and C5, there is also an M or an N.

These markings don't make a lot of sense - I think some of the text is missing as the case is cracked and charred (see attached photo).

The impact driver uses 18V batteries and I think the trigger mechanism is rated for up to 25A. I've ordered some 1N4001's but I don't think these are going to be up to the job.

Trigger switch is a Marquardt 2701.6306.

What diode would you recommend I use?

[image: Diode]

[image: Switch]

Comment: How sure are you that the diode is the only thing damaged? What burnt up the diode?

Comment: Yeah every time I've seen a blown flyback diode the mosfet is blown too.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry I forgot to mention - the MOSFET was also blown but I have replaced it and checked the 555 driver chip is ok too.

Comment: I replaced the diode with a 1N4001 today but had no luck - adding this diode appears to cause a short bringing the battery voltage down to 9V. When the diode is removed the switch works as expected. Could this component be something else?

Comment: Check the voltage across the diode contact points. Is it possible you put the diode in backwards?

Answer (score 1):

The diode needs to be a fast recovery type, usually a Schottky too. A regular rectifier diode is too slow and will be overloading the output as you’ve seen.

Answer (score 0):

Any 3Amp diode soldered in that place watching its polarity band, should do the job, it is to absorb high voltage spikes when forward motor current switches off, it generates a reverse current that can destroy the circuit and output switching transistor or hexfet or mosfet used as an output speed control transistor.

Comment: Please edit your answer and add punctuation. Without punctuation, your answer is hard to parse and difficult to understand. Thank you.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try 1N5401, or 1N5404. These are 3 A, 50 or 200 V diodes.